# Close Boostrap Modal AFTER form submit - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a remote form in my rails app:

```
<%= form_for(@list_item, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  .............
  .............
  <%= f.submit("Add It!", class: "btn") %>
<% end %>
```

It's contained in a Bootstrap modal with id 'addListItem'. I want to dismiss this modal after submitting the form. I've found a few similar questions on SO, but none that has answered this in a way that prevents the form from submitting BEFORE the modal is closed. Help please?

Comment: Are you responding w/ a js.erb template on your create action?

Comment: No, there's nothing to update on the page.

Answer (score 4):

To dismiss the modal after form submit.

JavaScript

```
$('#form_id').on('submit', function() {
  $('#addListItem').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Have you changed `$('#form_id')` with the actual id of the form? And check if js-script is loaded. Also you could play with your modal from browser console with commands: `$('#addListItem').modal('hide');` and `$('#addListItem').modal('show');` to see it works

Comment: Yes I changed the ID in the js and on my form to match. I will try the console out.

Comment: So the modal won't close the first time I hit submit. It will dismiss on the second click though. Any ideas why?

Comment: Please note that the colon at the end should be a semi-colon.

Answer (score 1):

Add a click event on your submit button using jQuery:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('#addListItem').modal('toggle');
});
```